# Why the filter function is not working with Titan 1.0.0

Tags: titan, gremlin

I am using Titan(titan-1.0.0-hadoop1). Let's say the node has a property `unique1`. I want the nodes with this property not equal to a particular value.

The query I have is:

```
g.V().filter(!it.unique1 = x)
```

I always get the error:

```
no such property, "unique1"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should study the [TinkerPop docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/) a bit better as this is really a very basic query.

```
g.V().has("unique1", neq(x))
```

Comment: Hello, the reason I am asking this question is because I want to know why "it" cannot be followed by an attribute of the node. According to the document, this should be allowed. Not the query itself. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: "it" is for lambdas. Are you looking for this: `g.V().filter {it.get().value("unique1") != x}`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Sample Graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open();
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> v1 = graph.addVertex();
==>v[0]
gremlin> v2 = graph.addVertex();
==>v[1]
gremlin> v1.property("unique1", 1);
==>vp[unique1->1]
gremlin> v2.property("unique1", 2);
==>vp[unique1->2]
```

Then filter your traversal like so:

```
// g = graph.traversal()
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().filter(values("unique1").is(1));
==>v[0]
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().filter(values("unique1").is(2));
==>v[1]
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().filter(values("unique1").is(3));
gremlin>
```